# Paypal Refund amount using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I have successfully implement PayPal with laravel. I am able to make payment using PayPal APIs. Now I want to implement refund from PayPal using laravel. I don't want to make refund from PayPal dashboard but i want to make it done from our admin panel where admin user can see list of payments and link to refund that amount to customer. After successful payment I got Transaction id in response from PayPal. If i use that transaction id to refund then i am not able to do that successfully, and if i copy transaction id from paypal dashboard where all transactions are listed and get detail information of that transaction, then i am able to make refund success. Can anyone tell me how can i get that transaction id using which i can make refund using laravel.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266949/refund-users-using-paypal-rest-api check this out.

Comment: This link is not useful to me

Comment: You can check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588772/refund-using-php-paypal-rest-api/62215463#62215463

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use below code to get actual sale id to refund amount using code not from paypal dashboard

```
$apiContext = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential(
                "<CLIENT_ID>", "<CLIENT_SCRET_KEY>")
        );
$payments = Payment::get($payment_id, $apiContext);
$payments->getTransactions();
$obj = $payments->toJSON();//I wanted to look into the object
$paypal_obj = json_decode($obj);//I wanted to look into the object
$transaction_id = $paypal_obj->transactions[0]->related_resources[0]->sale->id;
$this->getRefundPayment($transaction_id);

public function getRefundPayment($transaction_id){
    $this->API_UserName  = urlencode($this->API_Username);
    $this->API_Password  = urlencode($this->API_Password);
    $this->API_Signature = urlencode($this->Signature);
    $this->version = urlencode($this->version);
    $transactionid = $transaction_id;
    $DataInArray['currencyCode'] = 'INR';
    $DataInArray['refundType'] = 'Full';
    $DataInArray['transactionID'] = $transactionid;
    $DataInArray['invoiceID'] = '';
    $DataInArray['memo'] = 'This is refund of transaction id ='.$transactionid;
    $DataInArray['amount'] = '';
    if(trim(@$DataInArray['currencyCode'])=="")
        return array("ERROR_MESSAGE"=>"Currency Code is Missing");
    if(trim(@$DataInArray['refundType'])=="")
        return array("ERROR_MESSAGE"=>"Refund Type is Missing");
    if(trim(@$DataInArray['transactionID'])=="")
        return array("ERROR_MESSAGE"=>"Transaction ID is Missing");
    $Api_request = "&TRANSACTIONID={$DataInArray['transactionID']}&REFUNDTYPE={$DataInArray['refundType']}&CURRENCYCODE={$DataInArray['currencyCode']}";
    if(trim(@$DataInArray['invoiceID'])!="")
        $Api_request = "&INVOICEID={$DataInArray['invoiceID']}";
    if(isset($DataInArray['memo']))
        $Api_request .= "&NOTE={$DataInArray['memo']}";
    if(strcasecmp($DataInArray['refundType'], 'Partial') == 0)    {
        if(!isset($DataInArray['amount']))   {
            return array("ERROR_MESSAGE"=>"For Partial Refund - It is essential to mention Amount");
        }    else     {
            $Api_request = $Api_request."&AMT={$DataInArray['amount']}";
        }
        if(!isset($DataInArray['memo']))   {
            return array("ERROR_MESSAGE"=>"For Partial Refund - It is essential to enter text for Memo");
        }
    }                      
    $curl_var = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_var, CURLOPT_URL, $this->API_Endpoint);
    curl_setopt($curl_var, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_var, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl_var, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl_var, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_var, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $Api_request_final = "METHOD=RefundTransaction&VERSION={$this->version}&PWD={$this->API_Password}&USER={$this->API_UserName}&SIGNATURE={$this->API_Signature}$Api_request";
    curl_setopt($curl_var, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $Api_request_final);
    // Get response from the server.
    $curlResponse = curl_exec($curl_var);
    if(!$curlResponse)
        return array("ERROR_MESSAGE"=>"RefundTransaction failed".curl_error($curl_var)."(".curl_errno($curl_var).")");
    // Extract the response details.
    $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $curlResponse);
    $aryResponse = array();
    foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value)     {
        $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
        if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1)   {
            $aryResponse[$tmpAr[0]] = urldecode($tmpAr[1]);
        }
    }
    if((0 == sizeof($aryResponse)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $aryResponse))
        return array("ERROR_MESSAGE"=>"Invalid HTTP Response for POST request ($reqStr) to {$this->API_Endpoint}");
   // var_dump($aryResponse);
    return $aryResponse;
}
```